# What is a representation?

Tags: c++

In *The C++ Programming Lanugage*, 2.3 User-Defined Types, p47, Bjarne Stroustrup refers to "**representations**", but what does it mean exactly?

---

He writes,

> The C++ abstraction mechanisms are primarily designed to let
>   programmers design and implement their own types, with suitable
>   *representations* and operations, and for programmers to simply and elegantly use such types.

Then in chapter 3, under Concrete Types, he writes,

> The defining characteristic of a concrete type is that its
>   representation is part of its definition.

This is where I realized I didn't know what was going on.

---

I've been programming since 15, and am now 59 and I already know what types, abstractions, and operators are.  But this  representations word is new to me in the scope of programming languages.

Comment: The question should be "What does Bjarne mean by "representation" . Have you tried reading on to see if he elaborates?

Comment: He's not the only one to use this word.  For example, others talk about the representation of a key code in terms of binary, octal, or hex.  But I don't see how that relates to User-Defined types.

Comment: in Standard C++ "representation" means how a value is represented in memory. I couldn't say whether that's what Bjarne meant here

Comment: And yes, I'm into chapter 3, and searched the index, but all references to it are in the end of the book.

Comment: Would it be then how a user-defined type is represented in memory.  Ok, but if so then isn't that the job of the compiler, and we don't really care how the compiler does this???

Comment: In chapter 3, under Concrete Types, he writes, "The defining characteristic of a concrete type is that its representation is part of its definition."  This is where I realized I didn't know what was going on.

Comment: Some people might care about it

Comment: My guess as to what he might mean by representation, from the quotes you've provided, would be the internal data members used to represent the type/class. It's hard to be sure, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type's representation is basically how its state is stored in the computer.  An int on most platforms is *represented* by a sequence of four bytes in little endian order, for example.  When Stroustrup says that a concrete type's representation is part of its definition, he means that you can see how its state is defined by looking at its collection of members and base classes.